# Same storage directory for both views in Clearcase View Creation Wizard?

Tags: java, websphere, clearcase

I'm in ClearCase Project Explorer and I'm trying to create a view.  I right click on a project and choose create view.  I tick both the Create a development view and the Create and integration view checkboxes and choose Snapshot for both.  I click next and then put c:\MyDev for the root of the development view and c:\MyInt for the root of the integration view.  When I click on next I see:

You've specified the same storage directory for both views. 
You'll need to change one of them.

Huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should look like:

[image: specified the same storage directory for both views]

While the GUI might have evolved, double-check the advanced option when creating the views (as seen in the technote "[Create a snapshot view from Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21252574)").

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21252574&aid=1]

If you don't have declared a view server location, you would need to specify a common shared path, For ClearCase to store `view1.vws` and `view2.vws` (the view storage folders).
[See here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147128) for the nature of the view storage (The view storage directory tracks information about what files are loaded and checked out within the view).

[This thread mentions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013964530&ps=25&tags=&query=&filter=):

> When you join a project, two views are created:
>
> 1. A view attached to your new development stream and
> 2. an integration view attached to the project integration stream.
>
> The new development view will get created every time.
>   The integration view will get created if one does not already exist for the user (if one already exists, it can be reused).
>
> It is likely that the user is either specifying the same name for both views or is specifying the same view storage directory (e.g. `view-name.vws`) for both views.
>   There is nothing wrong with both view storage directories (e.g. `dev-view.vws` and `int-view.vws`) to exist in the same parent directory, just as long as the directory names are unique.

The [OP Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786805/eric) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768468/same-storage-directory-for-both-views-in-clearcase-view-creation-wizard/50770803?noredirect=1#comment88763703_50770803):

> I believe that there was an **invalid path** on one of the advance settings pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I don't believe that I have a view server location, the "Use server storage location" radio button isn't enabled.  I believe that I would then need to follow the *If you don't have declared a view server location* portion of your instructions?  I'll double check with another engineer who's more experienced with ClearCase and WebSphere to see if there's a view server somewhere.

Comment: Please double-check indeed: usually there is one view server already predefined, and accessible by all ClearCase users.

Comment: It's been a while since I got past this error message.  I believe that there was an invalid path on one of the advance settings pages.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.